# Can we do $all query in sails/waterline js?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am using `mongodb` and `sails/waterlinejs`

One of my documents has a field `"participants": ["1" ,"2" ,"3"]`

I would like to make a `mongodb` query:

```
Document.find({participants: {$all: ["1", "2"]}})
```

But I notice that if I do it in `waterline`, it returns me all the documents that contains EITHER `"1" OR "2"`.

I would like to get BOTH `"1" AND "2"`

Is this something that I have to do in native query? Does `waterline` have a doc somewhere that lists all the available operators for `.find()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$and`, You should do like this.

```
query = Model.where({"$and": [ { "participants": "1" }, { "participants": "2" } ] });
```